# Will Ubuntu work on MSI GE40?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop

I am going to buy a new laptop and I am thinking about MSI GE40 because of it's power and relatively low weight. But at the same time I am going to use it with Ubuntu. There are not too many posts about there "interaction" on Google, just a few with installation problems (UEFI-related).
So, the question is: does anyone have any experience or knowledge about using Ubuntu (or at least any linux) on this laptop? If yes, what to expect of it?

Answer (score 1):

Several Ubuntu versions gave me a black screen, apparantly a problem with the nvidia graphics card, so not only uefi problems. I did manage to install fedora 20 without too many problems though.